# show only one content in yii widget

Tags: php, yii

Hai I am trying to display some products view on yii if some condition is applied i have to limit contents in the following code:

```
 <?= ListView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'itemOptions' => ['class' => 'item'],
        'itemView' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
            return Html::a(Html::encode($model->name), ['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        },
    ]) ?>
```

I had added something like

```
pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 1,
    ],
```

But unable to get the desired result when i use pagination I am getting error

```
Setting unknown property: yii\widgets\ListView::pagination
```

how to limit content in view? is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think you did mistake. You have to use it in form:
    ...
    'pager' => ['pagination'=> ['pageSize' => 1]],
    ...
pagination is under the pager option

Comment: thank you for the answer but this solution not limits the data

Comment: Sorry but it sems my answer isn't right. It seems you have set pagination not on list view but on dataprovider. Please take a look on steps described here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/yii/yii_listview_widget.htm probably it will help. At all I'm using cListView and seems it is different there. Regards